# Is there a software that can draw a Bayesian model from JAGS?

Tags: r, bayesian, modeling, jags

I have a Bayesian model and I want to draw it like in the book [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FzvLAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=doing%20bayesian%20data%20analysis:%20a%20tutorial%20introduction%20with%20r%20doing%20bayesian%20data%20analysis:%20a%20tutorial%20with%20r,%20jags,%20and%20stan&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxgPi0tvHOAhWGXR4KHUYJAoAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=doing%20bayesian%20data%20analysis%3A%20a%20tutorial%20introduction%20with%20r%20doing%20bayesian%20data%20analysis%3A%20a%20tutorial%20with%20r%2C%20jags%2C%20and%20stan&f=false) page 225. I wonder if there is a software that exists that can do that.

[image]

I've done this by hand but I'm not sure about the structure. That's why I want to compare with a program.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried asking John Kruschke how he made the diagrams for his book?

Comment: WinBUGS (and maybe OpenBUGS?) have/had a graphical interface called `DoodleBUGS` (e.g. see http://www.stat.missouri.edu/~dsun/7640/pres.pdf ) where directed acyclic graphs (DAGs) could be drawn graphically and then converted into BUGS code, but (a) they're not as pretty as your/Kruschke's figure above and (b) I don't know if one can go the other direction (i.e., from BUGS code to picture)

Comment: Something like this can probably be constructed with Tikz in LaTeX. Maybe ask at the LaTeX stack exchange and they can help you make this diagram.

Comment: @dnbwise I saw [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55869/how-to-produce-john-kruschkes-bayesian-model-diagrams-using-tikz-or-similar-too) but I was thinking about something automatic

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Rasmus Bååth did exactly what you are looking for, by providing R scripts via his [distribution_diagrams](https://github.com/rasmusab/distribution_diagrams) repository.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer above, here's a blog post about exactly this issue:
http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2013/10/diagrams-for-hierarchical-models-new.html
The post described two different methods for creating the diagrams.